# How to prove $h\circ f$ injective implies $h$ is injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X, Y, Z$ be set and $f\colon X\to Y$ and $h\colon Y\to Z$. Suppose $h\circ f$ is injective. How can I prove that $h$ is injective? I have been able to show that $f$ is injective, but I dont know if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Given these conditions you will only be able to show that $h$ is injective if $f$ is surjective.

Then you would have

$$\begin{align}h(x') = h(y') &\Rightarrow h(f(x)) = h(f(y)) , \text{for some}\ \  x,y \in X \\ &\Rightarrow(h \circ f)(x)=(h\circ f)(y) \Rightarrow x = y \Rightarrow x' =f(x) = f(y) = y'\\&\Rightarrow x' = y'\end{align}$$

We conclude that $h$ is injective.

Otherwise this might not be true.

Answer (score 2):

$h$ need not be injective. As an example, let $f$ be the embedding of the integers in the real numbers, and $h$ be the floor function.

It is only necessary that the restriction of $h$ to the image of $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't help, because the result is false. Consider the functions
\begin{align}
&f\colon \{0\}\to\{1,2\},&& f(0)=1\\
&h\colon \{1,2\}\to\{3\},&& h(1)=h(2)=3
\end{align}
The function $h\circ f\colon\{0\}\to\{3\}$ is obviously injective, but $h$ isn't.

Note that this example also shows that $h\circ f$ surjective doesn't imply $f$ is surjective.